# how can I save a document id while adding that new document to firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add a new document to firestore, and inside that document I want to save its id as a property :

```
     await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("exmapleCollection).add({
    // more key/value pairs
    
    "id": /* here I want to set the auto-generated id for that document*/
```

any ideas?

Note: I don't want to set a hardcoded id, I want to get the firestore auto-generated id and se it

Comment: I want when a document is added to a collection, the id property save that document id as String value

Comment: I actually found a solution for the same question, but for an older version of firebase SDK, so I want to know what have been updated with

Comment: Thank you, but this is not a solution for firebase's flutter SDK, it's for the web, and this seems to get the id after adding the document to firestore, so I will need to update it again. i want a way to get that generated id from some firestore methd or a way then add the document with it

Comment: Some answers are creating ID before adding document. Every SDK have nearly same functionality.

Comment: See the second code snippet in the documentation on adding a document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document. The key piece of knowledge here is that calling `doc()` without any value doesn't write to the database yet but *does* create a new `DocumentReference` with its own unique document ID, that you can then write to.

Answer (score 1):

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("example").add({}).then((myNewDoc) =>
    print("Added Data with ID: ${myNewDoc.id}"));
```

**OR** using await as you have but with error handling...

```
Future<void> createNewDoc() async {
 try{
   const myNewDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("exampleCollection").add({});
   return ${myNewDoc.id};
  } catch (err) {
    print("Problem adding doc: $err");
 }
}
```

Just need to wait for the document to finish writing before receiving the id.